# Remove duplicate rows based on the value of another variable

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a duplicate date which I want to remove based on the value of another variable.  If one of dmean values for corresponding duplicates dates is NA I want to drop it.  If both dmean values for a certain date are NA I would like to keep any of the date. Sample data is found below:
I have tried

```
subset(df1, !duplicated(date))
```

but this removed all duplicates regardless of the value of dmean.    For example for date 2010-12-23   I would like to keep the the dmean value 28.38250 instead of the one with NA.

```
structure(list(date = c("2010-12-22", "2010-12-22", "2010-12-23", 
"2010-12-23", "2010-12-24", "2010-12-24", "2010-12-25", "2010-12-25", 
"2010-12-26", "2010-12-26", "2010-12-27", "2010-12-27", "2010-12-28", 
"2010-12-28"), dmean = c(NA, NA, NA, 28.3825, 35.54625, NA, 75.27625, 
NA, NA, 75.225, NA, 41.75, NA, 37.98375)), .Names = c("date", 
"dmean"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `plyr` :

```
ddply(df, .(date), summarize,
      dmean=ifelse(all(is.na(dmean)), NA, max(dmean,na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Which gives :

```
        date    dmean
1 2010-12-22       NA
2 2010-12-23 28.38250
3 2010-12-24 35.54625
4 2010-12-25 75.27625
5 2010-12-26 75.22500
6 2010-12-27 41.75000
7 2010-12-28 37.98375
```

Note that it is really easy to change the function call if you want the mean, the min or any other statistics of your `dmean` values.

You can do the same with `data.table`, too :

```
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,list(dmean=ifelse(all(is.na(dmean)), NA_real_, max(dmean,na.rm=TRUE))),by=date]
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you order the data frame by `date` and `dmean` first:

```
df1_sorted <- df1[order(df1$date, df1$dmean), ]
```

After the reordering, the `NA`s in `dmeans` are below the numeric values for each corresponding `date`.

Now, you can exclude the rows with duplicated dates:

```
subset(df1_sorted, !duplicated(date))
```

The result:

```
         date    dmean
1  2010-12-22       NA
4  2010-12-23 28.38250
5  2010-12-24 35.54625
7  2010-12-25 75.27625
10 2010-12-26 75.22500
12 2010-12-27 41.75000
14 2010-12-28 37.98375
```

Comment: Beware, that if no copy of a date is `NA` one of them will still be dropped by this solution. Can that happen, @Meso?

Comment: @Backlin You are right. I suppose the data contain one or no `dmean` value. This is the case in the example.

Comment: @Backlin, in my data one date is always NA. But there are also occasions in which both dates are NA.